# Delete untracked files with eGit (Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, git

I've the following problem with eGit:

- I'm in the commit A with the repository just pulled.
- I create a file FILE, later i decide to discard it and go back to the previous point (before create the FILE).

I've this actions but none work:

- Select Reset project with the option `Hard (HEAD, index and working directory updated)`
- Stash the project and checkout other branch
- Checkout other branch (after this the file is still there!)
- Add the file to the index before and try the 3 options above

In all the cases the file persist with the question mark or plus icon depending on if it out or in the index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git clean -fdx -n  # remove the -n when you are sure you are ready
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works in the command line. Is there some way of do this without leaving eclipse?

Comment: I can not see an obvious option in Juno/jgit.  But Eclipse workspace will be at cross-purposes with the function as many people do not check in Eclipse workspace files/dirs. All I checkin here is Maven format projects, never any IDE project control data.

Answer (score 7):

Since [Egit 3.0 Kepler](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2013/06/11/egit-3-0-top-eclipse-kepler-feature-9/) (June 2013), a clean action has been added to the repositories view.

[image: clean egit action]

Answer (score 4):

This is [implemented in Egit version 2.1](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/New_and_Noteworthy/2.1#Delete_untracked_files_in_Staging_View_and_Repositories_View), which was released at 2012-09-27.